# After updating google play services library my project showing errors

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, android-2.2-froyo

For one of my android project, I had successfully integrated google play services and it was working fine. But now I have updated google plus services to revision 12 But now my project showing some errors.
For example in my signinactivity.java I have the following line

```
       `mPlusClient = new PlusClient(this, this, this, SCOPES);`
```

and it shows error, there is no constructor available but earlier there was no issues.
Like that

```
com.google.android.gms.plus.GooglePlusUtil not available
```

These type issues are happening. All this came after updating my google play services to revision 12.
The sample available in the extras/google/playservice folder is working fine with google play service library but my old code is not working. I read from somewhere that new revision of google playt service removed some codes. I think that may be the reason for my errors. How can I solve my issue .
Please help me friends

Comment: remove library project from your project and clean then delete the google play services.jar from your project /libs folder then again add google play service project as library in your project and clean.Hope this may help you

Comment: @ Sharad Mhaske...But the sample project available in the extras/googleplus folder is working fine. It have some changes from my old code. So I want to know that my old code will work again or not?

Comment: :May be their are changes in packages that u download may contains diff packages name for the classes.